# Extending a class and replacing one method, having swapped return types

Tags: typescript, class

I need a way to override a class method, and have it's return type be inferred.

```
class Root {
  example () {
    return 'string'
  }
  utilize () {
    return this.example()
  }
}

class Child extends Root {
  example () {
    return true
  }
}
```

Is there a way to have this sort of syntax, I get that even within the rules of classes itself you can't extend and replace example with a different type.

Comment: This violates the class and its invariants. Imagine expecting a Root, but being given an extension of Root that doesn't act like a Root. That's just asking for confusing or undefined behavior! Don't do this!

Comment: You *could* use a generic type instead (`Root<T = string>`), but I'm not sure if that's what you're really after.

Comment: If you make `Root`'s `example()` `any` or some other broad type, the `Child` can return a narrower type than Root, but you then only get type inference if you explicitly narrow a `Root` as a  `Child` object.

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK99zN), but then the compiler doesn't consider `Root` a subtype of `Child` even though `instanceof Child` implies `instanceof Root`.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz this is a neat trick for sure but it made me realize that I forgot to return within `utilize`, the main idea that's missing from this solution is that the extended (or `Child`) methods don't utilize its `.example`s return.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect something like this to work via inheritance.  You'd need at least one type assertion somewhere, like maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4Xj4W), but it opens up weird holes I'd be afraid of falling into.  If that works for you I could write up an answer.  If not, where do we go from here?  (Pls mention @jcalz thx)

Answer (score 1):

This is not inheritance, and it breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), from the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

If the inheritance is used just for code reuse, consider using composition instead.

Your example is too abstract, but I modified it using a composition. Here is a [TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYRRzw)

```js
interface IExampable<T> { 
    example: () => T;
}

class RootLogic<T> {
    constructor(private readonly exampable: IExampable<T>) {}

    utilize(): T {
        return this.exampable.example();
    }
}

class ExmapleWithString implements IExampable<string> {
    example() {
        return "I am a string";
    }
}

class ExampleWithBoolean implements IExampable<boolean> {
    example() {
        return false;
    }
}

const instace1 = new RootLogic(new ExmapleWithString());
const instace2 = new RootLogic(new ExampleWithBoolean());
console.log(instace1.utilize());
console.log(instace2.utilize());
```

Comment: Very interesting made this even a little more dynamic here: https://tsplay.dev/w6Lxem